# How do I change super + middle mouse button shortcut?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, resize

It appears that Ubuntu 18.04 uses the windows key to trigger window dragging and window resizing using the mouse.

I want to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+'*Right Mouse Button*' to resize a window, instead of the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+'*Middle Click*'.

How do I change this configuration? It would be even better if I could go back to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+'*Right Mouse Button*' instead of using windows key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `dconf-editor`, if not yet installed..install it by below command

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Search for "mouse-button-modifier" and change value to `<Alt>`

[image]

now search for "right-button" and make it to true.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler answer than the accepted one: open a terminal, and do these 2 commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences resize-with-right-button true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier '<Alt>'
```